# How to display a line in a text file when the next three (or more than) identical lines occur consecutively

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Sample file content:

```
display this line
1111 aaaa
1111 aaaa
1111 aaaa
1111 aaaa
don't display this line
1111
1111
```

The output should be `display this line`

Comment: is the `1111` a fixed string or is it **any** 3 identical lines that trigger printing the next line? If you have 5 identical lines in a row should the 4th and 5th lines be printed or do you need the 4th line to be different from the first 3? Would you take an `awk` solution rather than a `sed` one?

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed in extended regex mode:

```
$ sed -Ene '
    $!N;$!N;$d
    /^(.*)(\n\1){2}$/!D
    n;p
' file
display this line
```

Maintain 3 lines at any time in the pattern space. Keep chopping the top line from the pattern space till we see all 3 lines in pattern space identical OR we run into eof for which we close shop nd quit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have changed the question altogether.
GNU sed

```
sed -nre '
    $!N
    :loop
        $bend
        N
     /(\n[^\n]*)\1$/bloop
     :end;h;s/(.*)\n.*/\1/
     s/^//;treset
     :reset;s/\n/&/3;g;TD
     P;s/.*\n/\n/;:D;D
' file
 display this line
```

Answer (score 0):

`uniq -c` is helpful here:

```bsh
$ uniq -c file | tac | awk '$1 >= 3 {getline; print substr($0, 9)}' | tac
display this line
```

1. count the consecutive identical lines
2. reverse the output
3. find a line with the requested number of duplicates

   - get the next line and print it without the count
4. reverse the output again

A question: what if your file contains

```
a
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
ccc
d
```

Do you want to output `a` **and** `bbb`?

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution works for me. My file doesn't contain ccc lines. I only need to deal with bbb.